# Uniformly Bounded Sum of Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sin(jx)$ is uniformly bounded because I can express $\sin(jx)$ in terms of exponentials and use properties of a geometric series.

However, I am having a very difficult time showing that $\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sin(2^{j}x)$ is uniformly bounded. I believe that it is $not$, however I don't know if there is some trick or something I am not seeing.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin (jx)$ is uniformly bounded?